# how to display images in custom size in uitable cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i my iphone applicaion image in right of table cell are extracted from xml feed. Know i want to display them in fix size can any body help me out.
        bellow is the code

```
  int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
  imgstring=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
      UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            cell.imageView.image=img;
      cell.textLabel.text=headline;
```

Thanks in advance i will be waiting

Answer (score 1):

Set the content mode of your UIImageView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or to UIViewContentModeCenter if your images do not require any scaling.

```
[yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Take a look at the examples in the API. There is a better way to load images for table view cells.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages

And for a better understanding of the anatomy of table view cells read this:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html